# Cannot delete image from aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, image, express, amazon-s3

I want to delete one of the images stored in the AWS S3 bucket by express.js, but I am facing an issue. Below is the code I have written

```
const imageurl=req.user.imageurl.split("/");
  // console.log(imageurl);
  const imgfile=imageurl[imageurl.length-1]
  // imgfile[0] = "4a05123a-506f-4c22-896a-8b6595b95d66Cover.jpg"
  console.log(imgfile);
  const params ={
    Bucket: process.env.aws_bucket_name,
    Key: imgfile
  }
  s3.deleteObject(params, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
    console.log(data);
    res.status(200).send("File has been deleted successfully");
  });
```

Here, everything works fine but when I run this code and then look at my S3 bucket, the image is still present.

Comment: Do you get the 200 message that everything worked? The the object at the top-level of the S3 bucket, or in a sub-folder?

Comment: Yeah, I got 200 message.

Comment: s3 deleteObject will not return any error even if key doesn't exist. code to deleteObject seems correct, don't see any reason why it won't delete.

Comment: Don't know what I am doing wrong, anyway thanks.

Comment: Is the object at the top-level of the S3 bucket, or in a sub-folder? Why is it splitting on slashes?

Comment: Yeah, got it where I was doing wrong. My imgfile is an array that contains the string at the zero index. I was passing it as imgfile instead of imgfile[0].
Thanks

Comment: @SubhamKumar since you found your error I suggest you either post that as the answer or delete your question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem that was causing an error. My 'imgfile' is an array that contains the string at the 0th index. I was passing it as imgfile instead of imgfile[0].

So sorry for the trouble.
Thanks